# How do I capitalize every third character in my code C#?

Tags: c#, string, toupper

I'm learning about C# but there is something that's frustrating me. I was learning about strings methods and how they work.

```
public static void CaseFlip()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("             CaseFlip -- Output");
            Console.WriteLine("==============================================================================");


           for (int i = 0; i < text.Length; i ++)
           {
            char[]delimiters = {'/'};
            string[]splitString = text.Split(delimiters);


                for (int k  = 0; k < splitString.Length; k +=3)
                    {
                    string sub = text.Substring(0);
                    string remove = sub.Remove(4, text.Length);
                    string insert = remove.Insert(0, sub);

                    splitString[k] = splitString[k].ToUpper();
                    Console.WriteLine(splitString[k]);
                    }
           }
           Console.WriteLine(" ");

        }
```

and my string array is:

```
static string text = "You only have one chance to make a first impression/" +
        "Consider the source and judge accordingly/" +
        "You can do something for a day you can't imagine doing for a lifetime/" +
        "Are we not drawn onward, we few, drawn onward to new era/" +
        "Never odd or even/" +
        "Madam, I'm Adam/" +
        "What do you mean? It's not due tomorrow, is it?";
```

What to do?

Comment: There is a lot more in your code then simple capitalizing every third letter.  Can you reduce the sample code to just the that the question refers to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `Substring` to select the character you want to convert to upper case, and then use `Remove` to remove that original character from the string, and `Insert` to add the uppercase character back in. Because strings are immutable, you also need to store the intermediate steps in a variable to have the changes carry over to the next cycle.

```cs
public static void CaseFlip()
{
    Console.WriteLine("             CaseFlip -- Output");
    Console.WriteLine("==============================================================================");

    var splitString = text.Split('/');
    for (var i = 0; i < splitString.Length; i++)
    {
        var line = splitString[i];
        for (var k = 0; k < line.Length; k += 3)
        {
            var upperCasedCharacter = line.Substring(k, 1).ToUpper();
            line = line.Remove(k, 1).Insert(k, upperCasedCharacter);
        }

        Console.WriteLine(line);
    }

    Console.WriteLine(" ");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First `for` loop is not needed; a single loop should iterate for as many delimiters as there are in the text.
Also you will be getting an exception in this line

```
string remove = sub.Remove(4, text.Length);
```

since you are trying to create a new string by removing a portion of the whole text, starting from the 4th character and going for as many characters as text.Length - effectively going out of bounds.
Try this:

```
public static void CaseFlip(string text)
{
    Console.WriteLine("             CaseFlip -- Output");
    Console.WriteLine("==============================================================================");

    char[] delimiters = { '/' };
    string[] splitString = text.Split(delimiters);
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    for (int i = 0; i < splitString.Length; i++)
    {
        char[] charsInLine = splitString[i].ToCharArray();

        for (int k = 0; k < charsInLine.Length; k++)
        {
            sb.Append(k % 3 == 0 ? char.ToUpper(charsInLine[k]) : charsInLine[k]);
        }
        sb.Append(' ');
    }

    Console.WriteLine(sb.ToString());
    Console.WriteLine(" ");
}
```

You should consider using the **StringBuilder** class for string operations like this. To use it, simply add `using System.Text` to the top of your file.

Comment: Okay, that's cool. But, how do I capitalize every third character in string array?
 
For example that I'm trying to replicate:
```You onLy HavE oNe ChaNce to maKe A fIrsT iMprEssIon
ConSidEr The soUrcE aNd JudGe AccOrdIngLy
You caN dO sOmeThiNg For a Day yoU cAn'T iMagIne doIng foR a liFetIme
Are we noT dRawN oNwaRd, we feW, DraWn OnwArd to neW eRa
NevEr Odd or evEn
MadAm, I'M ADam
WhaT dO yOu MeaN? It'S nOt Due toMorRow, iS iT?```

Comment: Ah, sorry for not getting the question exactly. I've updated the code. You can also consider using StringBuilder as I did in my code, if you intend to reuse the output later and not just output it into the console.

Answer (score 0):

Strings are immutable. Invoking `SubString`, `Remove` and `Insert` will create a new string everytime and use memory for nothing.

A simple way to achieve what you are asking is to convert your string into a char array using `ToCharArray` and then iterate using a simple for loop. Inside the loop, you can check if the char at the position is both a letter and greater or equals to [ASCII](http://www.asciitable.com/) 97. Lowercase alphabet starts at 97.

To convert a lowercase letter into an uppercase letter is to simply substract 32 from the letter. Since you are modifying a char array, you aren't creating any new string in memory.

After capitalization is done, you can convert your char array into a string again using one of the String constructor.

```
var chars = text.ToCharArray();
for (int i = 0; i < chars.Length; i += 3)
{
    if (char.IsLetter(chars[i]) && chars[i] >= 'a')
        chars[i] = (char)(chars[i] - 32);
}

text = new string(chars);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's my take on this:

```
string text =
    "You only have one chance to make a first impression/" +
    "Consider the source and judge accordingly/" +
    "You can do something for a day you can't imagine doing for a lifetime/" +
    "Are we not drawn onward, we few, drawn onward to new era/" +
    "Never odd or even/" +
    "Madam, I'm Adam/" +
    "What do you mean? It's not due tomorrow, is it?";

string result = new string(
    text
        .Select((c, i) => i % 3 == 0 ? char.ToUpper(c) : c)
        .ToArray());
```

> You onLy HavE oNe ChaNce to maKe A fIrsT iMprEssIon/CoNsiDer thE sOurCe And juDge acCorDinGly/YoU cAn Do SomEthIng foR a daY yOu Can't ImaGinE dOinG fOr A lIfeTimE/ARe We Not drAwn onWarD, We Few, dRawN oNwaRd To New erA/NEveR oDd Or EveN/MAdaM, I'm AdAm/WhaT dO yOu MeaN? It'S nOt Due toMorRow, iS iT?

Comment: @LorenPechtel - I wonder what it's like learning LINQ first up. It might be better. I mean I started with Commodore Basic and 6502 machine code and I wouldn't wish those basics on people these days.

Comment: When LINQ works it's nice.  When it doesn't it's a royal pain to debug.  When you change something and break it it's a royal pain to debug.  I rarely use it for this reason.

Comment: @LorenPechtel - It's interesting to here different perspectives. One of the reasons I use LINQ because it is less likely to create buggy code in the first place. Usually it create clear, linear code, that is easy to reason about.

Comment: I agree with @LorenPechtel on that it is really hard to debug, although it looks much better and certainly makes the programmer 'feel good' about himself being able to express multiple chunks of code in just a few lines :)
I also think that it is a bit too advanced a topic for a person just starting out with strings.